# Apache won't start after changing virtualhost

Tags: apache

I tried to enable https on my development web. After changing the virtualhost, apache won't start.

Log:

> [Mon Dec 26 08:32:41.917835 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1100:tid 392] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Mon Dec 26 08:32:41.980237 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 1100:tid 392] AH02562: Failed to configure certificate vid:443:0 (with chain), check C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.crt/certnew.cer
>   [Mon Dec 26 08:32:41.980237 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 1100:tid 392] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
>   [Mon Dec 26 08:32:41.980237 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 1100:tid 392] SSL Library Error: error:140DC009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib
>   AH00016: Configuration Failed

Here are the code(httpd-vhosts.conf):

```html
# vid
<VirtualHost vid:443>
 SSLEngine on

 SSLCertificateFile "C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt\certnew.cer"
 SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.key\server.key"
 <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs">
  AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
 ServerAdmin tes@gmail.com
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
ServerName vid
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ServerName should be a domain, and the Common Name of your cert should exactly match the ServerName.

Answer (score 0):

it's working now, i re-issued again the certificate from my server. and i used Base 64 encoded.